# EntityManager closed when executing queries on different threads

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, entitymanager

I am trying to execute a couple of queries on different threads. There are 2 top level queries each executing on different tables at runtime. For executing the first set of queries (`executeQuery1()`), I spawn 2 different threads and they are processed well. From the output of these queries, I have to extract a list of ids and then fire another set of queries (`executeQuery2()`) on entirely different threads. As soon as the second set of queries are about to be submitted to the database, I see that EntityManager is closed and the application shutdown.

```
2022-04-28 22:34:29.529 TRACE 48403 --- [main] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'springApplicationAdminRegistrar'
2022-04-28 22:34:29.529 TRACE 48403 --- [main] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'mbeanExporter'
2022-04-28 22:34:29.529 DEBUG 48403 --- [main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2022-04-28 22:34:29.529 DEBUG 48403 --- [main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans
2022-04-28 22:34:29.529 TRACE 48403 --- [main] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'defaultValidator'
2022-04-28 22:34:29.529 TRACE 48403 --- [main] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'org.springframework.data.jpa.util.JpaMetamodelCacheCleanup'
2022-04-28 22:34:29.530 TRACE 48403 --- [main] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'threadPoolTaskExecutor'
2022-04-28 22:34:29.530 DEBUG 48403 --- [main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'threadPoolTaskExecutor'
2022-04-28 22:34:29.531 TRACE 48403 --- [main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'verticaEntityManagerFactory': [verticaTransactionManager]
2022-04-28 22:34:29.531 TRACE 48403 --- [main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'verticaTransactionManager': [transactionTemplate]
2022-04-28 22:34:29.531 TRACE 48403 --- [main] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'verticaEntityManagerFactory'
2022-04-28 22:34:29.531  INFO 48403 --- [main] c.b.a.n.h.c.VerticaDataSourceConfig$1    : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'vertica'
2022-04-28 22:34:29.531 DEBUG 48403 --- [main] o.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl  : HHH000031: Closing
2022-04-28 22:34:29.531 TRACE 48403 --- [main] o.h.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache      : Cleaning QueryPlan Cache
2022-04-28 22:34:29.531 TRACE 48403 --- [main] o.h.type.spi.TypeConfiguration$Scope     : Handling #sessionFactoryClosed from [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@77774571] for TypeConfiguration
2022-04-28 22:34:29.532 DEBUG 48403 --- [main] o.h.type.spi.TypeConfiguration$Scope     : Un-scoping TypeConfiguration [org.hibernate.type.spi.TypeConfiguration$Scope@44af588b] from SessionFactory [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@77774571]
2022-04-28 22:34:29.532 DEBUG 48403 --- [main] o.h.s.i.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl      : Implicitly destroying ServiceRegistry on de-registration of all child ServiceRegistries
2022-04-28 22:34:29.532 DEBUG 48403 --- [main] o.h.b.r.i.BootstrapServiceRegistryImpl   : Implicitly destroying Boot-strap registry on de-registration of all child ServiceRegistries
2022-04-28 22:34:29.532 TRACE 48403 --- [MyAsyncThread-4] j.i.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor : Preparing to begin transaction via JDBC Connection.setAutoCommit(false)
2022-04-28 22:34:29.532 TRACE 48403 --- [main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'verticaDataSource': [dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration, jdbcTemplate]
2022-04-28 22:34:29.532 TRACE 48403 --- [main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer': [jdbcTemplate, namedParameterJdbcTemplate]
2022-04-28 22:34:29.532 TRACE 48403 --- [main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'jdbcTemplate': [namedParameterJdbcTemplate]
2022-04-28 22:34:29.532 TRACE 48403 --- [main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': [jpaVendorAdapter, entityManagerFactoryBuilder]
2022-04-28 22:34:29.532 TRACE 48403 --- [main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'jpaVendorAdapter': [entityManagerFactoryBuilder]
2022-04-28 22:34:29.532 TRACE 48403 --- [main] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invoking close() on bean with name 'verticaDataSource'
2022-04-28 22:34:29.533  INFO 48403 --- [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : vertica-db-pool - Shutdown initiated...
2022-04-28 22:34:29.533 DEBUG 48403 --- [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : vertica-db-pool - Before shutdown stats (total=20, active=2, idle=18, waiting=0)
```

I have 2 datasources in my Spring Boot app and therefore have to configure datasources programmatically.

### AsyncConfiguration.java

```
@EnableAsync
@Configuration
public class AsyncConfiguration implements AsyncConfigurer {

    @Bean(name = "threadPoolTaskExecutor")
    public Executor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
        executor.setQueueCapacity(500);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("MyAsyncThread-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }

    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        return new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    }

    @Override
    public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        return new CustomAsyncExceptionHandler();
    }
}
```

### AsyncService.java

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class AsyncService {

    @Autowired VerticaRepository verticaRepo;

    @Async("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
    public CompletableFuture<List<Entity1>> execute1(String query) {
        List<Entity1> result = verticaRepo.executeQuery1(query);
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(result);
    }

    @Async("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
    public CompletableFuture<List<Entity2>> execute2(List<BigInteger> ids, String query) {
        List<Entity2> result = verticaRepo.executeQuery2(ids, query);
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(result);
    }
}
```

### VerticaDataSourceConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("vertica.datasource")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "verticaEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "verticaTransactionManager",
        basePackages = { "mypackage.repository" }
)
public class VerticaDataSourceConfig /*extends HikariConfig*/ {
    public final static String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "vertica";
    public final static String PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = "mypackage.entity";

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public HikariDataSource verticaDataSource() {
        HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();

        hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("vertica.datasource.jdbc-url"));
        hikariConfig.setUsername(env.getProperty("vertica.datasource.username"));
        hikariConfig.setPassword(env.getProperty("vertica.datasource.password"));
        hikariConfig.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("vertica.datasource.driver-class-name"));

        hikariConfig.setConnectionTimeout(Long.parseLong(env.getProperty("vertica.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout")));
        hikariConfig.setIdleTimeout(Long.parseLong(env.getProperty("vertica.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout")));
        hikariConfig.setMaxLifetime(Long.parseLong(env.getProperty("vertica.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime")));
        hikariConfig.setKeepaliveTime(Long.parseLong(env.getProperty("vertica.datasource.hikari.keepaliveTime")));
        hikariConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("vertica.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize")));
        hikariConfig.setPoolName(env.getProperty("vertica.datasource.hikari.poolName"));
        hikariConfig.setValidationTimeout(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("vertica.datasource.hikari.validationTimeout")));

        return new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean verticaEntityManagerFactory(
            final HikariDataSource verticaDataSource) {

        return new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean() {{
            setDataSource(verticaDataSource);
            setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
            setPersistenceUnitName(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
            setPackagesToScan(PACKAGES_TO_SCAN);

            Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
            jpaProperties.put("hibernate.ddl-auto", env.getProperty("vertica.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto"));
            jpaProperties.put("hibernate.show-sql", env.getProperty("vertica.jpa.hibernate.show-sql"));
            jpaProperties.put("hibernate.format_sql", env.getProperty("vertica.jpa.hibernate.format_sql"));
            jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("vertica.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect"));

            setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

            afterPropertiesSet();;
        }};
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager verticaTransactionManager(EntityManagerFactory verticaEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(verticaEntityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

### VerticaRepository.java

```
@Repository
public class VerticaRepository {
    //@Autowired
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "vertica")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Transactional
    public List<Entity1> executeQuery1(String queryStr) {
        // query.setParameter() can only replace parameters in WHERE clause of a query;
        // it cannot replace table or column names
        String replacedQuery = // replace table name and column name
        Query query = em.createNativeQuery(replacedQuery);
        

        List<Object[]> result = query.getResultList();

        List<Entity1> entities = new ArrayList<>();

        // fill entities list with result

        return entities;
    }

    @Transactional
    public List<Entity2> executeQuery2(List<BigInteger> ids, String queryStr) {

        String replacedQuery = // replace table name and column name; the table and col names are different from the ones in executeQWuery1()
        Query query = em.createNativeQuery(replacedQuery);
        

        List<Object[]> result = query.getResultList();

        List<Entity2> entities = new ArrayList<>();

        // fill entities list with result

        return entities;
    }
}
```

### BusinessService.java

```
@Slf4j
@Component("businessService")
public class BusinessService {

    @Autowired
    private String query1;

    @Autowired
    private String query2;

    @Autowired private AsyncService asyncService;

    public Void serve() throws Exception {
        
        List<CompletableFuture<List<Entity1>>> violationFutures = new ArrayList<>();
        
        for (iterate over some list not shown here; this will loop 2 times with different table and col name substitutions in the query) {
            violationFutures.add(asyncService.execute1(query1));
        }

        CompletableFuture<List<List<Entity1>>> vcf = sequence(violationFutures);
        List<Entity1> aggregatedViolations = new ArrayList<>();
        for (List<Entity1> list: vcf.get()) {
            aggregatedViolations.addAll(list);
        }

        int numProcessors = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        List<BigInteger> idList= //somehow get a list of ids from aggregatedViolations
        List<List<BigInteger>> partitionedList = ListUtils.partition(idList, numProcessors);

        List<CompletableFuture<List<Entity2>>> trendFutures = new ArrayList<>();

        for (List<BigInteger> ids: partitionedList) {
            for (iterate over some list not shown here; this will loop 2 times with different table and col name substitutions in the query) {
                trendFutures.add(asyncService.execute2(getIds(devices), query2));
            }
        }

        CompletableFuture<List<List<Entity2>>> tcf = sequence(trendFutures);

        // rest of the business logic is dependent on the above queries execution

        return null;
    }

    private static <T> CompletableFuture<List<List<T>>> sequence(List<CompletableFuture<List<T>>> futures) {
        CompletableFuture<Void> allDoneFuture =
                CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[futures.size()]));
        return allDoneFuture.thenApply(v ->
                futures.stream().
                        map(future -> future.join()).
                        collect(Collectors.toList())
        );
    }
```

I believe that this has something to do with the EntityManagers being used in multi-threaded env. However, when I read the documentation, @Transactional will supply a new EM everytime. If the `executeQuery1()` was able to run 2 queries in parallel on different threads, why is `executeQuery2()` closing the EM?